Ubuntu and Cuda with Hybrid GPU run OpenGL with Nvidia
I'm quite new to Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm trying to code with cuda but even after 2 days of debugging I still can not figure out my issue.
My issue is that when I run this code :
#include "../common/book.h"



__global__ void add(int a, int b, int *c){
    *c=a+b;
    

}

int main(void){
    int c;
    int *dev_c;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c,sizeof(int)));
    add<<<1,1>>>((int) 2,(int) 7,dev_c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(&c,dev_c,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("2 + 7 = %d \n",c);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    return 0;
}```

It return me 2+7=0 that is unexpected. 

though the cuda compiler return no error.

One of the possible reasons this does not work might be because OpenGL is running on my intel CPU.
I have tried all I can to change this without success. The main method I used is ``prime-select nvidia`` , but even though my prime-select query returns nvidia OpenGL still runs on Intel GPU according to glxinfo 

Here is some of my logs : 

Mon Sep 16 16:12:53 2024
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03              Driver Version: 560.35.03      CUDA Version: 12.6     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M        Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8             N/A /  200W |       4MiB /   2048MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1594      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                            1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

here is the deviceQuery from the test file given in the installation guide:
/deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          12.6 / 12.6
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
Total amount of global memory:                 1996 MBytes (2092892160 bytes)
(005) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:    640 CUDA Cores
GPU Max Clock rate:                            1176 MHz (1.18 GHz)
Memory Clock rate:                             2505 Mhz
Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
Total shared memory per multiprocessor:        65536 bytes
Total number of registers available per block: 65536
Warp size:                                     32
Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
Run time limit on kernels:                     No
Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
Device supports Managed Memory:                Yes
Device supports Compute Preemption:            No
Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
Compute Mode:
< Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >
deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 12.6, CUDA Runtime Version = 12.6, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS



And finally glxinfo | grep OpenGL: 

OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

Thank you so much for your help I'm actually doing this at university in a course but every one including the teacher use VS so I'm helpless in the configuration process



Please edit the question and add the Ubuntu version info. You do say this is a homework question should you not be figuring this out yourself?

Thank you for your answer ! I added my Ubuntu version sorry for that. The homework is about writing Cuda code. Me I struggle with the driver part, we are not evaluate on our capacity to set up a driver in a Linux environment. In fact we can also use the computer of the school where everything is preinstalled,  but for some language reason it's not a friendly environment to me (I'm an exchange student in China) and I would like to be able to make it work on my computer. –
